# IE9 xdr.open() does not work -- what am I doing wrong?

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer-9, cors

Here is my code.

I know it's pointing to localhost.  However, it should 404 for you.  If you can get it to 404, you're ahead of me.

I have used IE9's debugging console and I can get upto right before the "xdr.open()" call.

I do not see anything in the net panel.  Please help.

```
$('body').on('click','.click',function() {    
    if (window.XDomainRequest) {
            xdr = new XDomainRequest();

            xdr.onload = function() {
                xdr.contentType = "text/plain";
                alert('load');
            };

            xdr.onerror = function() {
                alert('error');                                      
            };

            xdr.onprogress = function() {
                alert('progress');
            };

            xdr.ontimeout = function() {
                alert('timeout');
            };
            xdr.timeout = 10000;


            alert('Preparing to open connection...');                
            xdr.open( 'GET', host + '/bookmarklet/saveData/' );
            alert('If you see this message, the connection is opened');

            xdr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );
            alert('If you see this message, the data has been sent!');
        }
});
```

EDIT: corrected a typo from copy/paste around xdr.setTimeout -- still doesn't work?

Comment: Also, I have access-control-allow-origin: * being set in my php document, but IE9 still says "access is denied"  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was sending the access-control-allow-origin: * header twice (once in .htaccess, once in php script)

Check "Raw Headers" not just "headers" using chromebug ;)